# the accounts-github package is causing my meteor user to have a null email

Tags: meteor, nullreferenceexception

I've added accounts-github to my meteor app, but when I try to access Meteor.user.services.github.email all i get is null.  Even though I know the email is set in my github account.  What am I doing wrong?  The field is there, seems like accounts-github should just fetch the email for me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the github api docs:

> Note: The returned email is the user’s publicly visible email address (or null if the user has not specified a public email address in their profile).

To get the private email address you need to add the `user:email` scope to your app.

If you're using `accounts-ui` its just

**Client side**

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {
        github: ['user:email']
    }
});
```

### Update

I've tried the code above and It gives a couple of issues. It appears github no longer sends the email data along with the other OAuth data. Adding this *as well as the above (for permissions)* fixes it:

What it does is gets the email data separately in a request to github and adds it to your user when they log in.

Add the github api package

```
meteor add mrt:github-api
```

**Server Side Code**

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(info) {
    var user = info.user;
    if(user) {

    var github = new GitHub({
          version: "3.0.0", // required
          timeout: 5000     // optional
      });

      github.authenticate({
        type: "oauth",
        token: user.services.github.accessToken
      });

      try {
        var result = github.user.getEmails({user: user.services.github.username});

        var email = _(result).findWhere({primary: true});

        Meteor.users.update({
          _id: user._id
        },
        {
          $set: {
            'profile.email': email.email,
            'services.github.email': email.email
          }
        })
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
      }
    }
  });
```

You can then access the email address as normal in `{{currentUser.profile.email}}` (html), `Meteor.user().profile.email`, as well as in the `services.github` object.

There is an advantage to doing this too, The email field will stay up to date if they change it on github and log in again.

Comment: Tried this and it's still giving me null for the email.  I did meteor reset to start from scratch and still can't get it.  I see that the github popup on login has the new permissions (I added a couple others to test it too).

Comment: @Ben after a bit of tinkering I got it working :) - Updated answer

Comment: I'll try this in a bit, thanks for your help, but shouldn't it just do this out of the box?  The accounts-google package does, for example...

Comment: confirmed that this works.  still, wish I didn't have to do this.  you should do a pull request on accounts-github that does this out of the box...

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this could be helped by an upstream fix in the accounts-github package. Lets open a support request on the Meteor issue tracker to see how this might be resolved.

Comment: I got a warning of mrt:github-api package for meteor post 0.9. I found this package is working: meteor add bruz:github-api.

Comment: Although that is a plausible solution, I wish I didn't have to do all the work. Have you opened a support request yet?