# How to always get email for users signing in with Github

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, meteor

I use meteor with packages:

```
accounts-ui            1.0.0  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
accounts-password      1.0.0  Password support for accounts
accounts-github        1.0.0  Login service for Github accounts
```

I need to get email when users sign up using Github account. I use code on client side:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    github: ['user:email']
  }
});
```

However, when I sign up, than I see in console:

```
Meteor.user()
...
{"_id":"(redacted)",
"profile":{"name":"Jacek Migdal"},
"services":{
  "github": {"accessToken":"(redacted)","email":null,"id":(redacted),"username":"jakozaur"},
  "resume":{"loginTokens":[{"when":"2014-09-01T19:20:50.655Z","hashedToken":"(redacted)"}]}},
"createdAt":"2014-09-01T19:18:08.064Z"
}
```

Why do I get `null` in email field? Is it a bug or am I doing sth wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github no longer gives out the email address this way.

See this post on how to extract it when the user logs in: [the accounts-github package is causing my meteor user to have a null email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689889/the-accounts-github-package-is-causing-my-meteor-user-to-have-a-null-email)

Comment: FYI: In Meteor 0.9.1 it worked as I would expected. Either github or Meteor fixed that for me. Hurray!